# What constraints should be applied to an image with variable height inside a tableCell (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following table cell with the following contents:

An **ImageView**, a button (left), a label, and another button (right).

The Table Cells will each have one image, but these images will all have variant heights. They will, however, have the same widths (the table's width).

My question is...

**What constraints (or code) should I apply to my ImageView so that the Table Cell resizes accordingly based on the ImageView's height?**

---

[image: The cell which holds the ImageView that needs to be resized]

---

Here is a piece of code I've tried to use. It's pretty much but I'm not quite sure what it actually does:

```
internal var aspectConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint? {
    didSet {
        if oldValue != nil {
            resizingImageView.removeConstraint(oldValue!)
        }
        if aspectConstraint != nil {
            resizingImageView.addConstraint(aspectConstraint!)
        }
    }
}

let aspect = image.size.width / image.size.height

self.aspectConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
    item: resizingImageView,
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
    toItem: resizingImageView,
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height,
    multiplier: aspect,
    constant: 0.0
)
```

Any help or guidance is really appreciated! Still new to Swift.

Comment: use automaticdimension to tableview along with constraint

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari - yes. I'm using both estimatedRowHeight and UITableViewAutomaticDimension to set up the tableView.

Comment: check raynderwich tutorial , thorugh autolayout it takes lot of time to manage , i did using tutorial use once

Answer (score 0):

I would create an outlet for the `UIImageView`'s height constraint (connecting the `UIImageView` and your `UITableViewCell` subclass). Within the `UITableViewCell` subclass, mutate the `heightConstraint.constant` based on the height of the image view.

Comment: I'll give this a shot.